# How to make an html div appear like a separate form or window using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am completely new to javascript and jquery so please bear with me.

When I click the "Add" button the form div should appear in the middle center of the page and the focus is on the form div. The rest of the page should look deactivated (I did this by setting the opacity) but whats happening is that all of the page including the form div is affected by opacity. The user cannot click anything apart from form div when form div is appearing. The page can be returned to the default setting only when the user clicks either "Save" or "Cancel" button.

The idea is like in facebook when you click the pictures.

Can somebody please give me the simplest example you can give. Please help. Thanks in advance.

I would suggest that you run my code so you can see what Im trying to do.

**`divformtest.html`**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.6.4min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadDefault () {
 $("div#wrapper").css('opacity', '1.0');
 $("div#form").hide();
 $("div#formEdge").hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 loadDefault();
});

$(function(){
 $("input#btnShowForm").click(function(){
  $("div#wrapper").css('opacity', '0.1');
  $("div#form").show();
  $("div#formEdge").show();
  $("div#formEdge").height($("div#form").height() + 20);
  $("div#formEdge").width($("div#form").width() + 20);
 });

 $("input#btnSave").click(function(){
  loadDefault();
 });

 $("input#btnCancel").click(function(){
  loadDefault();
 });
});
</script>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnShowForm" value="Add"  />
<br /> <br />
<div id="formEdge">
<div id="form">
 <table id="tblForm">
  <tr>
   <td>First Name:</td>
   <td><input type="text" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Last Name:</td>
   <td><input type="text" />  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Address: </td>
   <td><input type="text" />  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Contact Number:</td>
   <td><input type="text" />  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" />  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2">
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
     <tr>
      <td><input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save"> </td>
      <td><input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel"> </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to use is a [Modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal). This will bring your form to the fore in a div, whilst making the underlying page inaccessible until either the modal dialog is cancelled, or your form within it is completed.

Comment: Is modal dialog behaving like a normal div??? I mean can I manipulate it the same way I do with divs?

Comment: That's correct. A modal dialog is created as a normal div, and you can put any content you like within it. It's then the jQuery plugin which stops the underlying page from being used. If you click 'view source' in the link I posted you'll see how to write your code to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) to your page and use its [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) widget in modal mode.

This works by using `z-Order` in the CSS to place the dialog at the front, and then covers the rest of your page content with another div that's transparent:

Usage for your requirement is *something* like:

```
var $div = $('#form');
$div.dialog({
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
       Save: function() {
           $(this).dialog("close");
       },
       Cancel: function() {
           $(this).dialog("close");
       }
   },
   close: function() {
       $(this).dialog('destroy'),
   }
});
```

This automatically creates the buttons - no need to add them to the div yourself.

Comment: I just downloaded jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom. Am I to import everything on my page?

Comment: you don't need all of them - if you go back to the jQueryUI website you can create a custom download where you just tick the dialog widget and it will tick the dependencies for you.

Comment: In my code, Am I gonna remove the entire <div id="form"> and use the code you gave me?

Comment: keep the div, but you don't need any buttons in it.  but beware that your page then _requires_ javascript, and won't work without it.